# Cassandra table with one primary key, one clustering column, and one regular column does not append data. It overwrites it

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, nosql

I imagine I must be missing something fundamental.

The table definition I have is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bundle_components (
    bundle_id uuid,
    component_type text,
    component_id uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (bundle_id, component_type)
);

CREATE INDEX ON bundle_components(component_type);
CREATE INDEX ON bundle_components(component_id);
```

However, I seem to only end up with a *single* `component_id` per unique `bundle_id` and `component_type` combination. I was under the impression that the table would have wide rows, so that I would have multiple `component_ids` if they have the same `bundle_id` and `component_type` combination.

Here's the problem in action. Two `INSERT` statements with different values for `component_id`, results in a single entry (the previous entry is overwritten):

```
cqlsh:voltron> INSERT INTO bundle_components(bundle_id, component_type, component_id) VALUES(8d8e8b6e-19dc-4af6-9bb7-500cd8e2dbaf, 'script', 6558981e-1d89-43c3-a1fc-b2cf45119bcc);
cqlsh:voltron> select * from bundle_components ;

 bundle_id                            | component_type | component_id
--------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------
 8d8e8b6e-19dc-4af6-9bb7-500cd8e2dbaf |        channel | a02069df-be81-4960-b64e-9ed8ee09550f
 8d8e8b6e-19dc-4af6-9bb7-500cd8e2dbaf |         script | 6558981e-1d89-43c3-a1fc-b2cf45119bcc

(2 rows)
cqlsh:voltron> INSERT INTO bundle_components(bundle_id, component_type, component_id) VALUES(8d8e8b6e-19dc-4af6-9bb7-500cd8e2dbaf, 'script', 7fcf4402-c8b3-41ed-a524-b1b546511635);
cqlsh:voltron> select * from bundle_components ;

 bundle_id                            | component_type | component_id
--------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------
 8d8e8b6e-19dc-4af6-9bb7-500cd8e2dbaf |        channel | a02069df-be81-4960-b64e-9ed8ee09550f
 8d8e8b6e-19dc-4af6-9bb7-500cd8e2dbaf |         script | 7fcf4402-c8b3-41ed-a524-b1b546511635
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary key is `(bundle_id, component_type)`, so you can only have 1 unique combination of `(bundle_id, component_type)`.

What you probably want to do is add component_id to your primary key (`(bundle_id, component_type, component_id)`), which will let you have multiple components with the same bundle_id and component_type.  With that change I get the following output:

```
cqlsh:test> select * from bundle_components ;

 bundle_id                            | component_id                         | component_type
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------
 8d8e8b6e-19dc-4af6-9bb7-500cd8e2dbaf | 6558981e-1d89-43c3-a1fc-b2cf45119bcc |         script
 8d8e8b6e-19dc-4af6-9bb7-500cd8e2dbaf | 7fcf4402-c8b3-41ed-a524-b1b546511635 |         script
```

Depending on how you want to be able to query your data, you may what to change the ordering of component_id and component_type, but I'm guessing you would like to query your data by `bundle_id, component_type` instead of `bundle_id, component_id`

Comment: Thank you! I was always a little confused about the `PRIMARY KEY (...)` statement because you could use it to define a regular primary key, a primary key with clustering columns, a compound primary key, or even a compound primary key with clustering columns. I was wondering if I would have to include `component_id` as part of the `PRIMARY KEY` definition (exactly for the reason you stated, but I was just assuming that was the case) and I'm glad that I was on the right track, but even more, thank you for providing a good explanation as to why that solution makes sense.